# Why do bulls-eye rashes look like they do?

Tags: microbiology, immunology, pathology, bacterial-toxins

People infected with Lyme Disease often present with an erythema migrans ("migrating redness") rash. Most often, these rashes are in the shape of a bulls-eye.

[Rash image](https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/articles/health_tools/bad_bugs_slideshow/cdc_photo_of_lyme_disease_bullseye_rash.jpg).

Presumably, this is a reaction that many of our bodies have to the *Borrelia burgdorferi* pathogen.

Lyme disease also sometimes presents with different-looking rashes, and other pathogens also sometimes produce a bulls-eye-looking rash. [CDC Link on Lyme Disease Rashes and Look-alikes](https://www.cdc.gov/lyme/signs_symptoms/rashes.html).

What causes the bulls-eye shape of these rashes?

Thought process: A gradient of redness from the site of the tick bite makes sense--an immune response might be strongest at the bite site--but I'm still stumped on why there would be a spot of redness surrounded by a no-rash-ring surrounded by a rash-ring.

---

Note: If I remember correctly, external links to images are usually frowned upon. Although the images linked in this post aren't super graphic, I decided to make them external links for the sake of anyone who is sensitive to medical images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spreading of the rash is caused by dissemination (migration) of the Lyme spirochetes (*Borrelia*) through the skin out from the initial site of infection.

The spirochetes trigger a immune reaction that involves macrophages entering the skin and releasing pro-inflammatory factors.

The clear areas (when present) apparently represent areas where macrophages have been cleared from the skin and thus are no longer triggering a inflammatory response.

The different patterns associated with the rashes can be explained by differences in how fast macrophages are cleared from the skin.

Reference:
[Vig, D. K., & Wolgemuth, C. W. (2014). Spatiotemporal evolution of erythema migrans, the hallmark rash of Lyme disease. Biophysical journal, 106(3), 763-768.](https://www.cell.com/biophysj/fulltext/S0006-3495(13)05809-8)